# RelationshipGroupStore mapped_memory setting for BatchInserter?

Tags: neo4j

I'm inserting relationships into Neo4j via the BatchInserter (as part of the initial data insertion). The process quickly slows down to 1,000,000 per ~1hr. The rest of the data (12,390,251 relationships, 6 million nodes, 74 million properties) goes in in less than an hour.

I've identified the culprit as the RelationshipGroupStore is increasing by only a few bytes at a time. While it starts off at 2megs increases in the file size, it eventually slows down to only a few bytes at a time.

I'm curious if this is related to the memory_mappnig, but there doesn't seem to be an option for the RelationshipGroupStore for the BatchInserter (probably the rest of the Kernel as well).

I've tried putting the following into the configuration but it did not seem to have an effect

```
neostore.relationshipgroupstore.db.mapped_memory=2G
```

Any ideas? Should I not do this in BatchInserter (50 mln Relationships for my current dataset, many more for others). I also believe this was much faster with older versions of Neo4j. As you can imagine 50 million relationships over 6 million nodes creates lots of highly connected nodes, which Neo4j 2.1.X have handled very well when it comes to query speed. I'm just trying to speed up insertion now.

Neo4j 2.1.5
Java: Various Versions, 1.7, 1.8
OS: Ubuntu, Mac OS X, CentOS

Neo4j Configuration:

```
neostore.propertystore.db.index.mapped_memory=1M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=1G
neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.mapped_memory=1M
store_dir=data.db
dump_configuration=true
use_memory_mapped_buffers=true
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=512M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=2G
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=2G
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=1G
```

JVM Settings

```
"-Xms10G"
"-Xms10G"
"-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
"-XX:+UseBiasedLocking"
"-XX:+AggressiveOpts"
"-XX:+UseCompressedOops"
"-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods"
"-XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis"
"-Xss4096k"
"-d64"
"-server"
```

Here are the logs showing the speed decrease:

```
2014-Oct-19 00:42:43 -0500 - 1000000 correlations recorded
2014-Oct-19 01:06:36 -0500 - 2000000 correlations recorded
2014-Oct-19 01:33:45 -0500 - 3000000 correlations recorded
2014-Oct-19 02:02:27 -0500 - 4000000 correlations recorded
2014-Oct-19 02:35:37 -0500 - 5000000 correlations recorded
2014-Oct-19 03:11:37 -0500 - 6000000 correlations recorded
2014-Oct-19 03:55:40 -0500 - 7000000 correlations recorded
2014-Oct-19 04:45:53 -0500 - 8000000 correlations recorded
2014-Oct-19 05:46:36 -0500 - 9000000 correlations recorded
2014-Oct-19 06:50:18 -0500 - 10000000 correlations recorded
2014-Oct-19 08:05:46 -0500 - 11000000 correlations recorded
```

And then I aborted it. I've tried forcing a GC after each 1,000,000 relationships, and "throttling" by giving a 20 second sleep, but none have seemed to help. I've removed the GC force but have left in the Sleep, although neither seem to help much.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Interesting, did you try to profile it, using YourKit or something similar? Are you storing things in HashMaps that serve as caches (something -> neo4j node ID) for the duration of the import?

Comment: Regarding the relationshipgroupstore, that does seem to be missing from the configuration options, I would create an issue here: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues

Comment: Thanks a lot Joseph for raising this, this was really an oversight on the Neo4j side, my apologies. If you add that option (with 10M is enough) you get improved read and write performance.

Comment: I'm still not seeing the performance improvement there with the bulk inserter, and have had to chance the super node density to 500 to get acceptable inserter performance. Unfortunately I'm writing and finishing this project to publish it, and haven't had a chance to write a small amount of code to demonstrate.